# Questions about jooq escape Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

i want comment

```
 Settings settings = new Settings()
            .withBackslashEscaping(BackslashEscaping.ON); // Default to DEFAULT

    settings.getBackslashEscaping();
```

ex)

```java
String idOrFragment = "it's test";
String test = idOrFragment.replace("'","\\'");

NewsDetailModel resultData = ctx
                .select(NEWS.fields())
                .select(ASSET.fields())
                .from(NEWS)
                .leftJoin(ASSET).on(NEWS.THUMBNAIL_ASSET_ID.eq(ASSET.ID), ASSET.DELETED_AT.isNull())
                .where(getDefaultCondition(NEWS.ID.cast(String.class).eq(test).or(NEWS.URL_FRAGMENT.eq("E"+test)), "NEWS"))
                .and(NEWS.CATEGORY.eq(NewsCategory.feature_stories))
                .fetchOne(record -> {
                    final NewsRecord news = record.into(NEWS);
                    final AssetRecord thumb = record.into(ASSET);
```

this my source

```java
.where(getDefaultCondition(NEWS.ID.cast(String.class).eq(test).or(NEWS.URL_FRAGMENT.eq("E"+test)),
```

Postgres News ID has a data type of UUID. So I cast it as a String. Assuming that the value of the test variable is, for example, it's test, the data goes into it's test.

Because I entered the data of it's test, I couldn't select that data.

```java
Settings settings = new Settings () during jooq configuration
                .withBackslashEscaping (BackslashEscaping.ON); // Default to DEFAULT
```

If you write this article, it will be escaped, but it is not used at all.

If you missed anything, please comment. I'm not good at English, so I'm a bit strange to turn the translator.

java, spring boot, jooq, kotlin, postgresql

Comment: `BackslashEscaping` is a flag that should only be used in legacy MySQL setups, because MySQL supports non standard escaping of apostrophes in string literals, (`\'` instead of `''`), and jOOQ needs to be aware of this. So, that part of your question is already in your attempted solution space. I'm curious about your actual problem. From your question, I'm not sure yet, what you're actually trying to achieve. Would it be possible to edit your question, to remove all the `BacklashEscaping` bits, and show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry. The problem I'm trying to achieve is that it's test <-I hope this data is written as where data. However, it's recognized that it is not possible to select the data.

Comment: I looked for the information elsewhere, so I needed BackslashEscaping to recognize the li's test data.

Comment: And thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: The reason why I asked you to edit your question and remove `BackslashEscaping` again is because this turned into an instance of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). As it stands now, the question is all about Y, but your actual problem is X, and I still don't understand what your X is. I think it would be best to start again by editing your question, and re-phrasing it anew. I don't think I can really help you, otherwise.